# Schedule task to run hidden in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, windows-task-scheduler

I have an exe file that I've created using pyinstaller. I am using Inno Setup to create a Windows installer for this executable.

Here's a snippet from my compiler script :

```
Filename: "schtasks"; \
  Parameters: "/Create /F /SC MINUTE /MO 2 /TN ""Discovery"" /TR ""'{app}\Discovery.exe'"""; \
  Flags: runhidden runminimized
```

I'm using `schtasks` to schedule the execution of my exe file (`Discovery.exe`). The scheduling works perfectly fine but a command line window still appears when the file runs. This leads me to believe that there's something weird happening with `runminimized` and `runhidden`

`Discovery.exe` is in fact a command line application created using pyinstaller.

How do I ensure that no command line window shows up when this file is supposed to run?

---

Final working [Run] statement on Inno Setup based on the answer by @Bill_Stewart:

```
[Run]
Filename: "schtasks"; \
  Parameters: "/Create /F /SC MINUTE /MO 5 /TN ""Discovery"" /TR ""'wscript.exe' '{app}\RunHidden.js' '{app}\Discovery.exe' "" "; \
  Flags: runhidden runminimized;
```

Note the usage of quotations due to spaces in my file paths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `runhidden` flag in Inno Setup's `[Run]` section is running the **schtasks** command, and the **schtasks** command is scheduling your program (**Discovery.exe**) to run. When the package installs, the **schtasks** command runs hidden as requested, but this doesn't mean that the scheduled task you are creating will run **Discovery.exe** as a hidden process.

If you are running the scheduled task as the current user, the Task Scheduler doesn't have a "run this task hidden" setting. However, you can work around this by creating a short WSH script:

```js
// RunHidden.js
// Runs a program in a hidden window
// Run this script using wscript.exe

var Args = WScript.Arguments;

if ( (Args.Unnamed.Count == 0) || (Args.Named.Item(0) == "/?") ) {
  WScript.Echo('Usage: wscript RunHidden.js "command"');
  WScript.Quit(0);
}

var FSO = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var Command = Args.Unnamed.Item(0);
if ( ! FSO.FileExists(Command) ) {
  WScript.Echo("File not found - " + Command);
  WScript.Quit(2);  // ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
}

var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.Run('"' + Command + '"',0);
```

You can distribute the above script with your installation. Schedule **wscript.exe** as the program to run, the above script and **Discovery.exe** as parameters, and the scheduled task should run the command without a window.